# capture both eyes in python haar cascade

Tags: python, opencv

I want to detect both eyes from image, but when I use Haar cascade it returns each eye separately. what should I do to crop both eyes together from the image? here is my code:

```
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
        crop_img = roi_color[ey: ey + eh, ex: ex + ew]
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (255, 255, 255), 0)
        path = r'C:\\Users\MJ-INFO\Desktop\projet\age-gender-estimation-master\test'
        cv2.imwrite(path+'\\'+ compteur, crop_img)  # use path here
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Or` operation on them.
for example for 2 rectangles you can use:

```
c = []
for i in eyes:
    c = c|i
cv2.rectangle(src_image,c,Scalar(0,200,0),1)
```